# Post review for anonymous, save as draft or save unpublished

Tags: nodes, forms

I have a form that allow anonymous user to send a job offer. Everything working fine but I don't want users to be able to publish node on the spot. I want it to publish as a draft/unpublished for reviewing before.

Can I alter my form in some way to prevent this?
Like only use save unpublished button action.

Answer (score 0):

Does your form after submission creates a node programmatically? If so you can just set the status of the node to 0.

Comment: No, it's set by drupal like a regular add form. I don't do anything programmatically. Everything is manage by drupal. It seems like you can't only display "Save as a draft" button action. It's always the two sided button